# QScrollArea in QGroupBox

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qwidget, qscrollarea

I'm trying to implement the following architecture:

- QGroupBox -->setLayout

  - QVBoxLayout -->addWidget

    - QScrollArea -->setWidget

      - QWidget -->setLayout

        - QVBoxLayout -->addWidget

          - My widgets(Mesures)

The result I'm looking for is having a groupbox with a scrollarea inside with all my widgets.
But when I try to implement this there is nothing in the scrollarea.

Here is what I have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkeSq.jpg

Edit: This is what I have when I remove the scrollarea and directly put my widget in the gorupbox https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bk1T.jpg

And here is my code:

Mesure.h

```
#ifndef MESURE_H
#define MESURE_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QString>

class Mesure : public QWidget
{
    public:
    Mesure(QString angle, QWidget *parent);

    private:
    QHBoxLayout *m_hlayoutMesure;
    QToolButton *m_buttonClose;
    QLabel *m_labelAngle;
    QCheckBox *m_checkboxMesure;
};

#endif
```

Mesure.cpp

```
#include "Mesure.h"

Mesure::Mesure(QString angle, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    m_hlayoutMesure(new QHBoxLayout(this)),
    m_buttonClose(new QToolButton(this)),
    m_labelAngle(new QLabel(angle, this)),
    m_checkboxMesure(new QCheckBox(this))
{
    m_buttonClose->setText("X");
    m_labelAngle->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    m_hlayoutMesure->addStretch(1);
    m_hlayoutMesure->addWidget(m_checkboxMesure);
    m_hlayoutMesure->addWidget(m_labelAngle);
    m_hlayoutMesure->addWidget(m_buttonClose);
    m_hlayoutMesure->addStretch(1);
    m_hlayoutMesure->setSpacing(10);
    m_hlayoutMesure->setMargin(0);

    QObject::connect(m_buttonClose, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
}
```

PanneauMesure.h

```
#ifndef PANNEAUMESURE_H
#define PANNEAUMESURE_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QString>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QSpacerItem>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <vector>
#include "Mesure.h"

class PanneauMesure : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
    PanneauMesure();
    void add(Mesure *mesure);

    public slots:
    void remiseAZero();

    private:
    QVBoxLayout *m_vlayoutTotal;
    QGroupBox *m_groupboxMesures;
    QVBoxLayout *m_vlayoutGroupBoxMesures;
    QScrollArea *m_scrollareaMesures;
    QWidget *m_widgetMesures;
    QVBoxLayout *m_vlayoutMesures;
    QGroupBox *m_groupboxOptions;
    QVBoxLayout *m_vlayoutOptions;
    QCheckBox *m_checkboxAfficherMesures;
    QPushButton *m_buttonRAZ;
    QWidget *m_widgetAlpha;
    QHBoxLayout *m_hlayoutAlpha;
    QLabel *m_labelAlphaText;
    QLabel *m_labelAlphaValeur;
    QSlider *m_sliderAlpha;
};

#endif
```

PanneauMesure.cpp

```
#include "PanneauMesure.h"

PanneauMesure::PanneauMesure() :
    QWidget(),
    m_vlayoutTotal(new QVBoxLayout(this)),
    m_groupboxMesures(new QGroupBox("Mesures", this)),
    m_vlayoutGroupBoxMesures(new QVBoxLayout(m_groupboxMesures)),
    m_scrollareaMesures(new QScrollArea(m_groupboxMesures)),
    m_widgetMesures(new QWidget(m_groupboxMesures)),
    m_vlayoutMesures(new QVBoxLayout(m_widgetMesures)),
    m_groupboxOptions(new QGroupBox("Options", this)),
    m_vlayoutOptions(new QVBoxLayout(m_groupboxOptions)),
    m_checkboxAfficherMesures(new QCheckBox("Afficher les mesures", m_groupboxOptions)),
    m_buttonRAZ(new QPushButton("Remise à zéro", m_groupboxOptions)),
    m_widgetAlpha(new QWidget(m_groupboxOptions)),
    m_hlayoutAlpha(new QHBoxLayout(m_widgetAlpha)),
    m_labelAlphaText(new QLabel("Alpha :", m_groupboxOptions)),
    m_labelAlphaValeur(new QLabel("50", m_groupboxOptions)),
    m_sliderAlpha(new QSlider(m_groupboxOptions))
{
    // Alpha
    m_sliderAlpha->setMaximum(100);
    m_sliderAlpha->setValue(50);
    m_hlayoutAlpha->addWidget(m_labelAlphaText);
    m_hlayoutAlpha->addWidget(m_labelAlphaValeur);
    m_labelAlphaText->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
    m_labelAlphaValeur->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
    m_sliderAlpha->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    QObject::connect(m_sliderAlpha, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), m_labelAlphaValeur, SLOT(setNum(int)));

    // Afficher Mesures
    m_checkboxAfficherMesures->setChecked(true);

    // Options
    m_vlayoutOptions->addWidget(m_buttonRAZ);
    m_vlayoutOptions->addWidget(m_checkboxAfficherMesures);
    m_vlayoutOptions->addWidget(m_widgetAlpha);
    m_vlayoutOptions->addWidget(m_sliderAlpha);

    // Mesures
    m_scrollareaMesures->setWidget(m_widgetMesures);
    m_vlayoutGroupBoxMesures->addWidget(m_scrollareaMesures);

    // Total
    m_vlayoutTotal->addWidget(m_groupboxOptions);
    m_vlayoutTotal->addWidget(m_groupboxMesures);

    setLayout(m_vlayoutTotal);
}

void PanneauMesure::add(Mesure *mesure)
{
    m_vlayoutMesures->addWidget(mesure);
    QObject::connect(m_buttonRAZ, SIGNAL(clicked()), mesure, SLOT(close()));
    QObject::connect(m_buttonRAZ, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(remiseAZero()));
}

void PanneauMesure::remiseAZero()
{
    m_sliderAlpha->setValue(50);
    m_checkboxAfficherMesures->setChecked(true);
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "PanneauMesure.h"
#include "Mesure.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    PanneauMesure panneau;
    Mesure mesure1("14°", &panneau);
    Mesure mesure2("12°", &panneau);
    Mesure mesure3("9°", &panneau);
    Mesure mesure4("8°", &panneau);
    Mesure mesure5("7°", &panneau);
    Mesure mesure6("5°", &panneau);
    Mesure mesure7("2°", &panneau);
    Mesure mesure8("1°", &panneau);

    panneau.add(&mesure1);
    panneau.add(&mesure2);
    panneau.add(&mesure3);
    panneau.add(&mesure4);
    panneau.add(&mesure5);
    panneau.add(&mesure6);
    panneau.add(&mesure7);
    panneau.add(&mesure8);

    panneau.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `QScrollArea` view (the internal scrolled part) doesn't adjust its size when its content changes, you can change that with either:

```
m_vlayoutMesures->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize);
```

or

```
m_scrollareaMesures->setWidgetResizable(true);
```

The latter will also adjust the external size of the `QScrollArea` to avoid scroll bars when possible.